# First option from slect menu is set to 'display:none' but it still displays

Tags: javascript, html-select, hidden

I was wondering if you can help me with the following:

I have a select menu, where I am hiding the first 3 options.
Although they have 'display:none' i can still see the first option. I was expecting to see 'Tomato (I ♥ JS shirt only)' as it is the next after the hidden ones...

```
<select id="color">
            <option value="cornflowerblue" class="puns">Cornflower Blue (JS Puns shirt only)</option>
            <option value="darkslategrey" class="puns">Dark Slate Grey (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
            <option value="gold" class="puns">Gold (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
            <option value="tomato" class="heart">Tomato (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option>
            <option value="steelblue" class="heart">Steel Blue (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
            <option value="dimgrey" class="heart">Dim Grey (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
          </select>

var punOption = document.getElementsByClassName('puns');
for(var i=0; i < punOption.length; i++) {
    punOption[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Thanks,
Alina

Comment: Why would you hide options from a select? Woodrow's answer would be the most appropiate use of a select.

Comment: I have explained already why. Thanks for your contribution though...

Answer (score 0):

You could mark your fourth option with a "selected" attribute on the option so it is selected by default. Or are you trying to dynamically change that via JS as well?

```js
var punOption = document.getElementsByClassName('puns');
for (var i = 0; i < punOption.length; i++) {
  punOption[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<select id="color">
<option value="cornflowerblue" class="puns">Cornflower Blue (JS Puns shirt only)</option>
<option value="darkslategrey" class="puns">Dark Slate Grey (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
<option value="gold" class="puns">Gold (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
<option value="tomato" class="heart" selected>Tomato (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option>
<option value="steelblue" class="heart">Steel Blue (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
<option value="dimgrey" class="heart">Dim Grey (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me so quick. Yes, I am trying to change it with javascript. When an user is choosing from another select menu the puns design they will see only the puns colors. And when they select the heart designs they see the heart options. Can I add select with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This works totally fine for me, exactly as you want it to be. I'm guessing you are having an issue with the script running before the DOM is loaded. Make sure to include your script tag after the HTML. Like this:

```
<select id="color">
  <option value="cornflowerblue" class="puns">Cornflower Blue (JS Puns shirt only)</option>
  <option value="darkslategrey" class="puns">Dark Slate Grey (JS Puns shirt only)</option>
  <option value="gold" class="puns">Gold (JS Puns shirt only)</option>
  <option value="tomato" class="heart">Tomato (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option>
  <option value="steelblue" class="heart">Steel Blue (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option>
  <option value="dimgrey" class="heart">Dim Grey (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var punOption = document.getElementsByClassName('puns');
  for(var i=0; i < punOption.length; i++) {
    punOption[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the top element becomes `selected`  by default. To get around this, you can set `selected` for a different element (in this case, when visible elements are always below the hidden ones, next neighbour works fine):

```js
var punOption = document.getElementsByClassName('puns');

for(var i=0; i < punOption.length; i++) {
    punOption[i].style.display = 'none';
    punOption[i].nextElementSibling.setAttribute('selected', true)
}
```

```html
<select id="color">
  <option value="cornflowerblue" class="puns">Cornflower Blue (JS Puns shirt only)</option>
  <option value="darkslategrey" class="puns">Dark Slate Grey (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
  <option value="gold" class="puns">Gold (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
  <option value="tomato" class="heart">Tomato (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option>
  <option value="steelblue" class="heart">Steel Blue (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
  <option value="dimgrey" class="heart">Dim Grey (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
</select>
```

**EDITED**

For more universal usage consider this code:

```js
// select the entire 'select' block
var color = document.getElementById('color');

// extract 'map' function to enable usage with HTMLCollection
var map = arr => fn => Array.prototype.map.call(arr, fn);

// here's your function
var hideClass = options => cl => {
  var selected = false; // flag is set once you define 'selected' attribute 
  map(options)(o => {
    if (o.className === cl ) { // the class you want to hide?
      o.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (selected === false) { // this class you don't want to hide && selected === false
      o.setAttribute('selected', true); 
      selected = true; // avoid multiple 'selected' set
    }
    return o;
  })
}

// work with all elements inside 'select'
hideClass(color.children)('puns') // here's your class you want to be hidden
```

```html
<select id="color">
  <option value="cornflowerblue" class="puns">Cornflower Blue (JS Puns shirt only)</option>
  <option value="darkslategrey" class="puns">Dark Slate Grey (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
  <option value="gold" class="puns">Gold (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
  <option value="tomato" class="heart">Tomato (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option>
  <option value="steelblue" class="heart">Steel Blue (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
  <option value="dimgrey" class="heart">Dim Grey (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to update the select element after that. Yea, html in kinda old is these aspects.

```js
var punOption = document.getElementsByClassName('puns');
for(var i=0; i < punOption.length; i++) {
    punOption[i].style.display = 'none';
}
var others= document.getElementsByClassName('heart');
document.getElementById('color').value=others[0].value
```

```html
<select id="color">
            <option value="cornflowerblue" class="puns">Cornflower Blue (JS Puns shirt only)</option>
            <option value="darkslategrey" class="puns">Dark Slate Grey (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
            <option value="gold" class="puns">Gold (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
            <option value="tomato" class="heart">Tomato (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option>
            <option value="steelblue" class="heart">Steel Blue (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
            <option value="dimgrey" class="heart">Dim Grey (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
</select>
```